# Time-Varying Inductance in Electrical Systems

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, differential, inductance, electromagnetic

How to derive and solve equations for electrical systems when the inductance of an inductor is not constant and changes over time?

I'm familiar with the standard equations like E = 1/2Li^2 or V = Ldi/dt, which work for constant inductance cases. However, I'm now dealing with scenarios where the inductance (L) itself is time-varying.

What equations and methods should I use to model and analyze such systems?

Comment: Is incremental or average inductance being changed? Put another way: is work being done upon the inductor externally? How shall you express that change in circuit?

Comment: @TimWilliams Consider a variable inductor for example , where the inductance changes by movement of a metal core inside the coil

Comment: It takes (or delivers!) force to move such a core. In general you have a coupled system, where both electrical and mechanical energy are connected. Thus your methods will have to represent both routes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already said that you should analyze the whole system - the electric circuit and the mechanism which varies the inductance - a multiphysics problem!

That's exactly true, but fortunately a crutch exists. If we assume that the magnetic field of the current in a circuit loop is still concentrated to an inductor we can start from the basic formula for the inductance concept. That formula is F = L * I , where I is the current, L is the inductance and F is the total magnetic flux through the inductor. Proving that such quantity L exists for current loops (assuming there's no radiation) is not trivial, but you can find it from university level texts which apply vector calculus and Maxwell's equations.

FYI: The corresponding basic formula for electric fields is Q = C * U where Q is the charge of a capacitor, C is the capacitance and U is the voltage.

When Maxwell's equations, vector integration and Stokes integration theorem are applied to a circuit loop one can find that the total voltage in the loop or the electromotive force, as theorists say, is the time derivative of the magnetic flux  = d(L * I)/dt

That gives the generalized equation u = L(di/dt) + i(dL/dt)

Small letters only is the common way to help to keep in mind that voltages and currents are momentary values, not averages nor RMS.

You already presented the same for a constant L.

I guess you also know how the constant L version should be modified if we assume some series resistance R is included. The total voltage for constant L and resistance R:

u= L(di/dt) + iR.

If we add what is caused by the varying inductance we get

u = L(di/dt) + iR + i(dL/dt) = L(di/dt) + i(R + dL/dt)

That points a place for the varying inductance. The growth rate of the inductance (henries per a second) is equivalent with a series resistance.

dL/dt can as well be positive or negative. Positive values sink electric energy like a resistor. Negative values generate it. The existence of both possibilities is already said by others. And I guess you remember that the dissipation power in a resistor  can be written

P = R(i^2) ; negative R means energy injection to the circuit.

The shown formulas are only for electricity. What actually happens in the whole system which has the varying L needs also the analysis of the mechanism which changes the inductance.

Comment: Thank you, I've used the equations in some simulations and it seems to correct. However I struggling understanding some parts, I think the voltage of i(dL/dt) is actually the EMF voltage. but where is it in the circuit ? At first, I thought that it is the voltage across the inductor, however it couldn't be, since the voltage across inductor is Ldi/dt which is not equal to EMF. I would be grateful if you could clarify this for me

Comment: Voltage across a constant inductance inductor is L(di/dt). Voltage across a varying inductance inductor is L(di/dt)+i(dL/dt) just as can be calculated from the most fundamental inductor formula Flux = L * I. Nothing less, nothing more if there's no resistance and the circuit is so compact that the radiation as radiowaves can be ignored.

Comment: if we sum up energy losses in this EMF voltage should it be equal to the energy which is converted to kinetic energy of moving core ? I'm asking this since I get EMF energy loss as exactly 2 times kinetic energy of the core in simulations and I don't know whether  my simulation is implemented incorrectly or is there something else which I am not taking into account